# Debounce callback while capturing debounced call arguments

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm listening to an event emitter and need to process all of the events that come in. But my app can't handle processing them one-by-one with the volume of events that come in. I'd like to debounce the event callback, but all of the debounce implementations I've seen drop the arguments for the debounced calls.

How can I debounce my callback in such a way that I still receive all of the arguments passed to the debounced calls, so I can process them in bulk?

Comment: How does an update look like, i.e. what are the arguments you need to batch up?

Comment: @javan A normal queue would still invoke one-by-one processing, and not batch updates.

Comment: @turtlefight that's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @spiffytech what store are you using? vuex? redux?

Comment: Svelte store. But if I were using Vuex or Mobx on another project I would still encounter this problem.

Comment: @spiffytech depends. vuex for example will automatically batch up multiple mutations and only update the views once the state has "settled"

Answer (score 4):

Given the vague details, my only recommendation would be to write a custom batch function that aggregates the arguments and then does a batch update.
You would need to define this function outside the store though.

You also need to come up with a way to combine multiple events into one, e.g.
by merging objects like in the following example:

```js
// debounces a given function for wait ms
// (aggregating up the arguments and then calling the fn function)
function debounceAgg(fn, wait = 50) {
  let timeout = null;
  let update = {};
  
  function processUpdate() {
    timeout = null;
    fn(update);
    update = {};
  }
  
  return value => {
    update = {...update, ...value};
    if(timeout == null)
      timeout = setTimeout(processUpdate, wait);
  };
}


function storeFn(args) {
  console.log("Called storeFn with:", args);
}

let debounced = debounceAgg(storeFn);

// those will be batched up
debounced({a: "fairytale"});
debounced({i: "love cookies"});
debounced({a: "banana"});
debounced({i: "am debounced"});
debounced({long: "string"});

// some time later
setTimeout(() => {
  debounced({another: "one"})
}, 100);
```

You could also use [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) instead of `setTimeout`, if you're ok with non-determistic update intervals.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what I need:

```
function myDebounce(fn, wait) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  let capturedArgs = [];
  let timeout = null;
  return arg => {
    capturedArgs.push(arg);
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null;
      fn(capturedArgs);
      capturedArgs = [];
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should maintain all of the updates without dropping, but loops within a setInterval to pool dispatched events/values. Obviously this would need to be tailored to the specific processing and timing. It also loosely mimics a situation where a lot of events may appear and processing needs to be batched.

```js
const updates = [];

function dispatcher(value) {
  updates.push(value);
}

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const batch = updates.splice(0, 20);
  if (batch.length) {
    console.log('batch', batch);
    /*
       here is where you can do some batch processing,
       or pass to the store for reactivity
    */
  }
}, 1000);

// just as a demonstration of multiple events
[...Array(100)]
  .map((_entry, index) => index)
  .forEach(entry => dispatcher(entry))
```

Comment: This will have an interval running at all times though, even if no updates need to be processed.

Comment: Admittedly there's a bit of guesswork here. I'm not familiar with Svelte store, but if this was in vuex I would set part of this logic within an action and react to changes on `updates`, while tracking time from last batch processing. Basically process `updates` if either it has a certain amount of events or some time has passed from the last batch being processed.

Comment: With vuex you don't need to batch updates manually, it has a built-in mutation merger. If you trigger many mutations at once, vuex will only update your components once the state has settled. [jsfiddle as example](https://jsfiddle.net/ec8evq7m/2/) (look at the console, the computed property will only be re-calculated once all 100 mutations went through)